# not updating if file is not selected in nodejs using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I am trying to update the data. It's working fine if I select the file but there is a problem when I just want to update any field excluding file input type. I am not able to update in such a condition.
How can I resolve it?

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, './public/uploads/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, file.originalname+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
}
});



var upload = multer({ 
storage:storage,
});


app.post('/editProfile', auth, upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const userEmail = req.user.email;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const filename = req.file.filename;
    const contact = req.body.contact;
    console.log(filename + "fghj");
    if(filename) {
    const edited = await User.updateOne({ 'email': userEmail }, {
        $set: {
            name: name,
            contact: contact,
            filename:filename
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        const edited = await User.updateOne({ 'email': userEmail }, {
            $set: {
                name: name,
                contact: contact,
                }
            });
    }
    res.redirect('profile');
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(`while edit profile ${e}`);
    res.status(400).send(e);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `filename` but remember you didn't send a file in your scenario. Here:

```
const filename = req.file.filename;
```

First, you should check if a file is exist or not.

You can revise your code like this:

```
app.post('/editProfile', auth, upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const userEmail = req.user.email;
        const name = req.body.name;
        // const filename = req.file.filename; Remove this line from here

        const contact = req.body.contact;

        if (req.file) {
            const filename = req.file.filename // And, use that code when you make sure that you have a file
            const edited = await User.updateOne({ 'email': userEmail }, {
                $set: {
                    name: name,
                    contact: contact,
                    filename: filename
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            const edited = await User.updateOne({ 'email': userEmail }, {
                $set: {
                    name: name,
                    contact: contact,
                }
            });
        }
        res.redirect('profile');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(`while edit profile ${e}`);
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
})
```

Comment: It's still not working. Getting the same error